# Which built-in excel functions treat ranges as arrays?

Tags: excel-formula

For example `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10-10)` does, but `=SUM(A2:A10-10)` does not. Specifically in my situation I wish `=MEDIAN(ABS(A2:A10-MEDIAN(A2:A10)))` did; however sadly it does not, and if I knew which built in functions convert the ranges into arrays before they evaluate then I might be able to reformulate something that gives me what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some natural array type formulas like SUMPRODUCT and some of the options in AGGREGATE, as well as some financial functions.

Many can be "forced" into array mode by simply using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

For example your formula:

```
=MEDIAN(ABS(A2:A10-MEDIAN(A2:A10)))
```

If it is confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode will "Force" the Array.  If done correctly the Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: that's pretty good, but is there a listing or maybe a VBA way to generate a listing of the ones which naturally act this way?

Comment: not sure, I found them by playing and sometime forgetting to hit the Ctrl-Shift-Enter and realizing the same number was returned.

Comment: The main two I use are SUMPRODUCT and AGGREGATE(Not all options are array).  I know the IRR formulas are also array,  but not being a finacial guy I do not use these much.  What I can't get done with SUMPRODUCT or AGGREGATE I just use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: FYI, to close off this [MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) example the outlier-robust mean would then be `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10)*(ABS(A2:A10-MEDIAN(A2:A10))<=B4))/SUMPROD‌​UCT(1*(ABS(A2:A10-MEDIAN(A2:A10))<=B4))`

Answer (score 2):

The [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) has an *Array Form*.

```
=SUM(INDEX((A2:A10)-10, , ))
```

In the above, INDEX is returning an array of values but a wrapping SUM is required to collect a total. The blank parameters represent all rows and all columns in the range (e.g. A2:A10) specified. All rows and all columns in the range can also be represented with zeroes in place of the blank parameters.

With *2* to *10* in A2:A10, your MEDIAN example would return 14 from,

```
=MEDIAN(INDEX(ABS((A2:A10)-MEDIAN(A2-A10)), , ))
```

(without CSE)

Use the Evaluate Formula command to see more of the inner workings of this style of INDEX use.

Comment: This is a good answer since it adds a non-aggregating function to the list which can be nested well, and it is better for my specific situation(once you fix they typo), but to really steal the check I'd like a more comprehensive listing of which functions exhibit this behavior... maybe if the question just ends up with a list of answers each with their own functions then I'll probably mark this one.

Comment: hmm the plot thickens; I hadn't considered this at first, but it looks like some functions don't go the other way for example `=SUMIF(INDEX(A2:A10-MEDIAN(A2:A10),,),"<="&B4,A2:A10)` and `=AGGREGATE(12,4,A2:A10-MEDIAN(A2:A10))`